# firebase-functions-test multiple firestore snapshots

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

I have a background function which will interact with multiple collections in my database. As such, I need to be able to mock out multiple documents across the collections being worked with. However, the examples in the docs and elsewhere online only provide one document snapshot when testing a function, never two or more. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
const wrapped = firebase.wrap(deleteUser);
const snap = firebase.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({
    userId: "1",
    firstName: "John"
}, "matches/1");
await wrapped(snap, {
    params: {
        userId: "1",
        matchId: "1"
    }
});
```

I do to do something like this, notice the array.

```
await wrapped([snap], {
    params: {
        userId: "1",
        matchId: "1"
    }
});
```